# Function that return a tuple (length_of_element,element)

Tags: ocaml

I wanted to know if there is a way in OCAML to return the length of the string element of a list of string and the element himself?
I want to do something like that:

```
let (length_of_element,element) = List.map String.length ["Hello"; "World!"] in .....
```

and I want the **in** keyword to pass into the next part of the code, the `length_of_element` which is the length of the element "Hello" (if we are at the loop 0) and the element itself , which is "Hello"  (if we are at the loop 0)

**UPDATE**

```
let () =
        let t = Sys.time() in
        let args_n = Array.length Sys.argv - 1 in
        let args_list = Array.to_list (Array.sub Sys.argv 1 args_n) in
        List.iter (fun element ->
        let length_of_element = String.length element in
        let text = check_if_file(List.nth args_list 1) in
        let int_ls = search (to_list_ch element) text length_of_element) check_if_file(List.nth args_list 0 ) in
        if (List.length int_ls)> 1 then print_string "pattern found at characters "
        else if (List.length int_ls) = 1 then print_string "Pattern found at character "
        else print_string "No patterns found."
        ;
        print_ls int_ls;
        Printf.printf "Execution time: %fs\n" (Sys.time() -. t);;
```

In my use case of this function, `check_if_file(List.nth args_list 0 )` is my list.

I tried to implement what **Guillaume Melquiond** told me in his answer but I get this error:

> Error: Syntax error: operator expected.

(The error points to this line :

```
let int_ls = search (to_list_ch element) text length_of_element) check_if_file(List.nth args_list 0 ) in
```

Would anyone be where this error came from?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way I can imagine would be this :

```ml
List.map (fun s -> String.length s, s) ["Hello"; "Everyone"]
```

which returns :

```ml
- : (int * string) list = [(5, "Hello"); (8, "Everyone")]
```

As for your edit, this :

```ml
let int_ls = search (to_list_ch element) text length_of_element) check_if_file(List.nth args_list 0 )
```

is ill-balanced : there is no opening parenthesis matching the closing one after length_of_element.

Comment: The thing's if i remove it there will not have closing parenthesis matching with this one :     ``List.iter (fun element ->`` When i remove it, i get a error saying that there no closing parenthesis matching with him.

Comment: Can you tell me what you want to do ? For now it's hard to tell, there are a lot of custom functions whose type I don't know. Also for now you anonymous function (the one that you're passing to List.iter) is ill-formed : it looks like  (fun element -> let x = whatever) which is not a valid function, it does not return anything - in this case it should return unit. For example if you want to print something it should look like (fun element -> print_endline (foo element)) - because print_endline return unit. Alternatively, it can be (fun element -> let x = foo element in print_endline x)

Comment: What i was trying to do was just passing into let int_ls = search (to_list_ch element) text length_of_element) (check_if_file(List.nth args_list 0 )) in the length_of_element and the element , through iterating in the (check_if_file(List.nth args_list 0)) given

Comment: So to do that i tried to implement what @Guillaume Melquiond give me.

Comment: The construct let x = ... (without in) is only valid at the toplevel. Inside an expression (as a function body) let should only be used in the following way : let x = ... in <some expression that uses x>. That's why you get a syntax error in the anonymous function passed to List.iter. You wrote something like List.iter (let int_ls= 2) list_to_iter. Inside the parenthesis, you are binding x but not using it anywhere.

Comment: So what should i do  ? should i ending the parenthese after the " print_ls int_ls;  ?
 "

Comment: Basically yes, without the ';' but you ought to put the list you iterate on after the closing parenthesis.  Something like List.iter (fun element -> let int_ls =  search (to_list_ch element) text length_of_element in print_ls int_ls) (check_if_file (List.nth args_list 0 )) - you have to put check_if_file (...) in parenthesis (another trick if to put @@ before check_if_file)

Answer (score 0):

It is quite complicated to perform external iterations in OCaml. It is much simpler to make them internal. This means that the body of your code needs to be passed to `List.map`, rather than the converse:

```ml
List.map (fun element ->
    let length_of_lement = String.length element in
    ... (* use element and length_of_element here *)
  ) ["Hello"; "World!"]
```

And if you do not care about producing a list, just use `List.iter` instead of `List.map`.

Answer (score 0):

Second question.

(You should ideally ask one question per StackOverflow post.)

Your extracted text has 3 right parentheses and only 1 left parenthesis. This might be related to your syntax error.

Comment: It's weird because there is one right parentheses matching with those above at List.iter